# How to keep the Date as it is without being converted into local time zone?

Tags: javascript

I am having issue with the localtime zone things in javascript. If I got a string value from the server is "2014-02-03T00:00:00.000Z", once I pass it into Date object new Date('2014-02-03T00:00:00.000Z'), the new date object will be in localtime zone ex. Sun Feb 02 2014 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST). How to keep the value as 'Mon Feb 03 2014 00:00:00' ? I see a lot of people is using moment.js for dealing date, but I don't find any help with this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I believe the Z adjusts the date to local time. Have you tried removing the Z?

Comment: still not working. I still get the same result even I removed 'Z' new Date('2014-02-03T00:00:00.000') and new Date('2014-02-03T00:00:00.000Z') have the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use getUTCDate() method. It will return you correct date.

http://jsbin.com/zizukapuba/1/edit?output

It will convert the date into required format with reference to system local timezone.

NOTE: If you use, the `getISOString()` method, then it will again make the changes with reference to your local time, that is, GMT -6.00.

Answer (score 0):

The Date object stores your date as "2014-02-03T00:00:00.000Z".

When you display your Date object, the toString() function is used to get a string to display the date. toString() displays the date using the local time zone. Try using the toISOString() function or toUTCDateString().

Comment: okay it will display '"2014-02-03T00:00:00.000Z", but I want the date object still as '"2014-02-03T00:00:00.000Z". It still shows my date object has been changed to my local time zone when I test it in my debugging console.